# React Native Flatlist "getItemLayout" makes it buggy

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using `scrollToOffset` and storing the current offset so I can return the flatlist back to the it's old state. However to use `scrollToOffset` I have to use `getItemLayout` but using it makes my flatlist buggy. With 50 items it's working fine but with 3000 items I'm not being able to scroll after first 200-300 items.

Flatlist renders text items so I tried to get different heights for items depending on their content:

```
<FlatList
        scrollEventThrottle={1}
        onScroll={this.handleScroll}
        ref={ref => (this.flatList = ref)}
        data={this.state.listData}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
        renderItem={this._renderListItem}
        removeClippedSubviews
        maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
        getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
              length: (data[index].title.length + data[index].body.length) ** 0.4 * 25,
              offset: (data[index].title.length + data[index].body.length) ** 0.4 * 25 * index,
              index,
    })}
/>
```

How can I solve this 'buggy scroll' problem? I have to use `scrollToOffset` so I can't remove `getItemLayout` property.

Item render function:

```
_renderListItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: (item.title.length + item.body.length) ** 0.4 * 25,
        }}
   >
    ....
    </View>
```